# How can I set up conditional associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

So I have two associated models Users and Magazines. They are associated by a has_many :through relationship via Subscriptions. So this is what it looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :magazines, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :magazine
end

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

Users have a boolean attribute called `paid`. I only want users where `paid == true` to be able to subscribe to any magazines. How can I set up a conditional association like this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the associations, you can pass a lambda before the hash options. In this lambda you can specify conditions, ordering, etc.

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, ->{ where(users: {paid: true}) }, through: :subscriptions
end
```

For users, you could do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :magazines, through: :subscriptions

  def magazines
    self.paid ? super : Magazine.none
  end
end
```

While it's neat, the above might behave unpredictably when you're joining tables e.g. `User.joins(:magazines)` might ignore the `paid` condition or crash.

A better alternative:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :subscriptions
  has_many  :magazines,
            ->{ where("subscriptions.user_id IN (
                  SELECT id FROM users WHERE users.paid = 't')") },
            through: :subscriptions
end
```

That `where` in the lambda might be replaceable by a `joins` like so:

```
joins(subscriptions: :user).where(users: {paid: true})
```

But I think that'll join `subscriptions` twice - once for the lambda and once for the association. I'm not certain. If so, and if that bothers you, then:

```
joins("INNER JOIN users ON (users.id = subscriptions.user_id)").
where(users: {paid: true})
```

or:

```
joins("INNER JOIN users ON (
  (users.id = subscriptions.user_id) AND (users.paid = 't')
)")
```

Also, I think you mislabeled your `Subscription` model as `Registration`

Comment: Oops, yeah model should be called `Subscription`, not `Registration`. Thanks for catching that.